Passing string parameters to an xslt 2.0 script does not work, but integers do
There is a problem trying to pass string parameters to an xslt 2.0 script, pure integer parameter work fine in this example, but a string like "value" or even "w1234" will fail to be accessable through $my_param in xslt.
Is this a known problem? (Gemini could not help, neither typical string() modifications in the code.) How can I make passing string parameters into XSLT 2.0 work?
Python:
from lxml import etree
xml_doc = etree.parse('input.xml')
xslt_doc = etree.parse('my_stylesheet.xslt')
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_doc)
result_tree = transform(xml_doc, my_param='value')
result_tree.write('output.xml', pretty_print=True)

XSLT-Stylesheet:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <param><xsl:value-of select="$my_param"/></param>
      </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <data />
</root>

Expected:
<root>
  <param>value</param>
</root>

Actual:
<root>
   <param/>
</root>

If my_param is 123 (or any other int, even 10-2 which results in <param>8</param>) does work fine. String values seem to get lost by executing the xslt script.

Python v3.12.4
lxml v5.2.2
Win10


Note that lxml supports XSLT 1.0 only (https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html).

In terms of XSLT, you should also declare a top level parameter <xsl:param name="my_param"/>.

Thank you for the hint about XSLT 1.0, using saxonche now, solved this issue for me.

Thank you for the declaration hint - anyway I was surprised it worked without, but "um sauber zu bleiben" a very useful declaration

You can use etree.XLST.strparam:
from lxml import etree
xml_doc = etree.parse('input.xml')
xslt_doc = etree.parse('my_stylesheet.xslt')
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_doc)
result_tree = transform(xml_doc, my_param=etree.XSLT.strparam('value'))
result_tree.write('output.xml', pretty_print=True)

Output:
<root>
  <param>value</param>
</root>


GREAT! Thank you very very much!
Followup question in context: same problem though, if multiple parameters are passed. How to apply in this situation:
parameters = {
'year': var_year,
'genre': var_genre,
'author': var_author
}
result_tree = transform(xml_doc, **parameters)

@BorisHoeller: Don't move the goalposts. You should accept this answer and post a new question if there are other issues.

Well, you'd want etree.XSLT.strparam(var) for each pair, so you'll need to construct parameters like that. Say, coming from a dict already, that would be parameters = {k: etree.XSLT.strparam(v) for k, v in {'my_param': 'value'}.items()}.

OK - sure and thank you very much!

Thanks again so much ouroboros1 - very kind of you!

You're very welcome. If the answer offers a solution to your Q, please consider accepting the answer to close the post.
